# How would drinking carb blend after workout affect my weight lose program?

Tags: weight-loss, supplements, programs, cutting, bulking

I have passed my bulking phase and have got a bit of muscle gain during that. From the beginning of this month, I starting the cutting phase with low calorie intake (about 1500 Cals a day - weight 5 feet 8 inches - 74 kg - skinny fat). I have been told by a professional to have protein and carb blend together after workout for maximum gains. I have took creatine for around 1-2 month(now in pause), took casine and still take it and have just started glutimne+amino focus rsp(bcaa and caffeine) during the workout. My goal is to at least cut 500cals a day and lose 10kg in 3 months -- mainly the belly fat, I got a freaking big tummy and skinny arms(12 inches).

My current diet structure is:

```
1. Morning 7am:         oats in milk(~300ml) with frozen berries.
2. Morning Tea 10am:    1 apple and 1 kiwi. green tea 1 bag in water.
3. Lunch 12:30pm:       boiled rice with boiled veggies and 1 can of Tuna/Salmon.  
4. Dinner 5:30 pm:      Chicken breast/thigh fillets fried in canola oil
                        and lemon juice with herb powders. Salad: half cucumber 
                        and 1 small tomato with some spit olives.  
5. Before Sleep 9/10 pm: YoPro High protein yogurt with some fruits(optional). 
                         I usually avoid this diet, so can say every second day I 
                         don't take this.
Supplements:  5gm scoop Creatine in juice. 1.5 scoop protein powder + 0.75 scoop
              of cab blend after workout(around 8-9pm). 1 scoop of casein before 
              sleep. 

Workout plan:  Each day for two muscle groups. 4-5 days a week. Example:  

Day1: Triceps and squats  
Day2: Biceps, Hams and Calves  
Day3: Rest  
Day4: Shoulders, Stomach  
Day5: Lats, Row pulley  
Day6: Chest and forearms/deadlift  
Day7: Rest

The basic idea is to hit two unconnected muscle groups on a single day, so
that soreness in one muscle group has least affect/involvement while working out on
the second muscle group. Plus, I hit one muscle group once a week only. I find
that if I hit one muscle group to death and then give complete time to recover
before hitting next time, it comes with increased strenght next time(gain!). It
takes my body to have at least 4 days from soreness to completely go. I also try to
keep every strength training session from 45mins to 1 hour. After finishing
strength training, if I don't feel to tired I go for cardio, nowadays boxing but
before I was doing cycling machine.
```

I just read Cals on the carb blend powder (I use Vitagro S2). It has 280cals per serving which is 2 scoops. I have been taking 3/4 of a scoop and rarely one whole scoop.

Should I cut this off from my diet or it doesn't make much fat and helps maintain the muscle more and gets converted to energy for muscle repair, that is has more good than harm?

Also how much time gap should there be between normal protein shake and casein?

P.S: I have followed this program strictly for around 2 months now. I started from 7 Nov 2019 and on 13 Jan 2020 I lost around 6kgs, from 74kg to 68kg.

Comment: This is not really answerable, as we don't know anything about your actual workout and you give no details on what else you are eating. It's basically a straight nutrition question with not enough details to answer. If you can edit those in, it would help prevent this from being closed. Also, cutting and bulking are sort of opposites, pick one or the other as your preferred tag.

Comment: @JohnP I have added more details about my eating and workout plan. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

Weight loss will happen with a caloric deficit. To maintain weight multiple current weight x 15. This will give you total calories for maintaining your weight each day. To lose weight subtract 15-25 % of that number and you will have the total number of calories you can consume up to each day and lose weight.

As far as drinking the carb blend I think it will better serve you before exercise as carbohydrates give you energy to fuel your workout.

All the best

Comment: 1. Is my weight considered in pounds or kgs for your formula? 2. The carb blend I am using says _same day recovery... after workout... to repair muscles soreness_. P.S: I have already lost 6kg since I asked this question :-)

Comment: sorry for that part not being clear. this formula is in pounds. I'm sure it will be fine before and/or after your workout. The point I'm trying to make is that it is your total consumption of calories in a given day that ends up having the most impact on weight loss. That being said though it does seem to be better to limit ones carbohydrates at night time when physical activity is lower. Carbohydrates are important for energy and recovery to some extent but when physical activity is lower such as before going to sleep they aren't needed as much. All the best

Comment: -1, this formula seems entirely arbitrary with no regard to age, sex, lean mass, activity, or anything else that other more accepted formulas do. Even the more accepted formulas are just estimations at best however and their accuracy for an individual is prone to vary. Also, how soon before a workout should carbs be consumed? How long does it take the body to convert consumed carbs into usable energy? The only thing this answer has going for it is the opening sentence.